# how to make mysql works in a R function

Tags: r, rmysql

I wrote a code using RMySQL package, it works as a code, but when I wrote it as a function it always returned

> Error in .local(dbObj, ...) : 
>     internal error in RS_DBI_getConnection: corrupt connection handle.

How can I fix the problem?

I took out function{}, and it works, but every time I put it back, it crashed. I also tried pinning down when the problem occurred, but cannot find the location.

```
move_data_summary <- function(path,DSfile,hostname,outpath){
  library(RMySQL)
  library(readxl)
  library(readr)
  library(stringi)
  library(tidyr)

  path <- path
  DSfile <- sprintf("%s/%s",path,DSfile)
  DS <- read_excel(DSfile,"RunSpec")

  pollutantID <- c(31,87,110)
  pollutant   <- c("NOx","VOC","PM2.5")
  ERRORfile <- sprintf("%s/data_summary_error.txt",path)
  if (file.exists(ERRORfile)) file.remove(ERRORfile)
  write(paste("total lines",length(DS$countyID)),ERRORfile,append = TRUE)

  for (c in 1:length(DS$countyID)){
    if(DS$countyID[c] %in% NA){
      write(paste("error data in line",c),ERRORfile,append = TRUE)
    }else{
      write(paste("finished data in line",c),ERRORfile,append = TRUE)
      database <- DS$`CDM Output Name`[c]
      mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='moves', password='moves',
                       dbname=database, host= hostname)
      on.exit(dbDisconnect(mydb))
      rs1 = dbSendQuery(mydb, "SELECT countyID, yearID, pollutantID, sourcetypeID, sum(emissionQuant) FROM movesoutput
                    group by countyID, sourceTypeID, pollutantID")
      data_tmp1 = fetch(rs1, n=-1)
      all_cons <- dbListConnections(MySQL())
      for (con in all_cons)
        dbDisconnect(con)
      tmpoutfile <- sprintf("%s/%s.csv",outpath,database)
      write.csv(data_tmp1,tmpoutfile)
      if (c == 1){
        data <- data_tmp1[which(data_tmp1$pollutantID == 31 |
                                  data_tmp1$pollutantID == 87 |
                                  data_tmp1$pollutantID == 110),]
      }else{
        data_tmp <- data_tmp1[which(data_tmp1$pollutantID == 31 |
                                      data_tmp1$pollutantID == 87 |
                                      data_tmp1$pollutantID == 110),]
        data <- rbind(data,data_tmp)
      }
    }
  }
  write("finished all data",ERRORfile,append = TRUE)
  return(data)
}
```

if I took out the function{}, it worked. Otherwise, show me the error,

> Error in .local(dbObj, ...) : 
>     internal error in RS_DBI_getConnection: corrupt connection handle
>   In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50).

I've used

```
all_cons <- dbListConnections(MySQL())
for (con in all_cons)
    dbDisconnect(con)
```

to disconnet the SQL server.

Comment: You should move the `mydb = dbConnect(...)` and `on.exit(...)` outside the loop probably. Just open the connection once; don't keep connecting/disconnecting.

Comment: You should be using `library(DBI)`, not `library(RMySQL)`. The only time you should need to reference the latter package is with `DBI::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), ...)`. (I don't think that's addressing your core problem here, but I believe it is a small bug in your use of the package. I don't think the package help pages *clearly* show this, but the repo [`README.md`](https://github.com/r-dbi/RMySQL/blob/master/README.md) does have this in its "hello world" example.)

Comment: moved mydb = dbConnect(...) and on.exit(...) outside the loop actually gave me the problem with connection allocation
Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Cannot allocate a new connection: 16 connections already opened

Comment: based on the record, it even passed line 58
write("finished all data",ERRORfile,append = TRUE), I added some statements after return(data), but it was not shown in the error log

Comment: You are using `for (con in all_cons) dbDisconnect(con)` to disconnect from all connections in your function, then as you try to exit (aka return) from your function it is trying to run `on.exit(dbDisconnect(mydb))` to try to disconnect from the database which is no longer connected. I suspect this may cause a similar error.

Comment: Thanks, after commenting out  #on.exit(dbDisconnect(mydb)), it works properly. Also thanks for DBI and RMySQL suggestion.